# PFQueryTableViewController crashes when preparing for segue (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

Bit of a head scratcher, using Parse for my backend and want to pass data to a PFQTVC with the following

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "propertyListSegue") {
        print("Segue data send!")
        let pvc = segue.destination as! ExtendedQueryViewController
        pvc.dataObj = "Woo!"
    } else {
        print("No segue data to send")
    }
}
```

Here's code for the PFQTVC

```
var dataObj: String!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print(dataObj)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Running it on a simulator, it just crashes when I try to open the PFQTVC with no reported errors

I've two other segues to a PFLoginViewController and a blank UITableViewController that work perfectly

xcode 8, ios 10

Comment: Is the `ExtendedQueryViewController` your PFQTVC? Also, what does the console say when it crashes? Nothing?

Comment: Really weird. Got frustrated, shut down to grab a coffee, then when I got back everything compiled and ran fine. Anyway, thanks for your help!